# How to get a paramater in the URL when page loads and make it available to be used in the page (using Wordpress)

Tags: php, string, wordpress, variables, get

Is there a simple way to:

1) Grab parameters in the URL
2) add them to URLS in the page

Example:

http://marianarodrigues.com.br/testewordpress/?var1=123&var2=abc

And Then I need to add these "123" and "abc" values to the end of a few hyperlinks that will be in the same page...

Hyperlink example: www.link1.com.br/?transaction_id=321&partnerid=123&clickid=abc

Note: I'd appreciate if somebody could send me something for dummies as I don't have much knowledge =)

Comment: They are called GET parameters so `$_GET['var1']` would be 123. http://learn.onemonth.com/understanding-http-basics http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Just read them from the $_GET array. For example: 'www.link1.com.br/?transaction_id=321&partnerid='.$_GET['var1'].'&clickid='.$_GET['var2']

Comment: take a look also at [`build_query` and `add_query_arg`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/127311/69071)

Answer (score 0):

See if this get's you pointed in the right direction.

```
$partnerid = $_GET('var1');
$clickid = $_GET('var2');

$URL = 'http://www.link1.com.br/?transaction_id=321&partnerid=$partnerid&clickid=$clickid';
```